# How can i transform this piece of code of ES6 into older version of javascript

Tags: javascript

I've found one solution written in ES 6  but i don't know how can i transform it on older version of java script so i cant understand it better.
If we have object we get with this code only some properties from that object.
But i don't understand what is happening here. what means (obj) at the end and how looks
this code in older version of java script?

```
const obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };
const result = (({a,b,c}) => ({a, b, c}))(obj);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: sure we could write it on our own or you just go to https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAhgLgIwBoZ5sAmQ4bAZkIBNsAWQgU2wFYYBfAbgChRJYAJyYQArgBtYaABTSs-ePmAcAlKgB8MOZkKKYylSukJEK3vwghxTAHTiQAc2nCxks0A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.4&externalPlugins= and copy paste your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like this:

```js
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };
var result = (function(o) {
    return { a: o.a, b: o.b, c: o.c };
})(obj);
console.log(result);
```

and to be more descriptive, this part:

```
var result = (function(o) {
    return { a: o.a, b: o.b, c: o.c };
})(obj);
```

means "*create an anonymous function that takes an object argument and returns a new object, and then execute it immediately with `obj` as an argument and assign the result to the `result` variable.*"

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a function and calling it below.

This is the same:

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };

var result = function(obj) {
  return {
    a: obj.a,
    b: obj.b,
    c: obj.c,
  }
}

result(obj);

console.log(result);
```

You can use Babel tool to transpile modern code:

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

which automatically transform ES6 to older versions.

This is the code that Babel generates from your code, which will will work with older versions:

```
"use strict";

var obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5
};

var result = function (_ref) {
  var a = _ref.a,
      b = _ref.b,
      c = _ref.c;
  return {
    a: a,
    b: b,
    c: c
  };
}(obj);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first ask what exactly You mean with 'older version', anyway the following is ES3 compliant, and should clarify:

```
var obj = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5 };
function middleFun(o) {
  return {a: o.a, b: o.b, c: o.c}
}
var result = middleFun(obj)
console.log(result)
```